# Why is this Velocity expression failing?

Tags: velocity

I am using Velocity to check if a string ends with a particular value, but I cannot get it to behave. I am using `$element.elementType.endsWith("startevent")`, which will print `true` or `false` correctly, but when I put it into an `#if()`, it behaves as if it were always true. I have even tried adding `.booleanValue() == 1`, `.booleanValue() == true`, and even `.booleanValue().toString() == "true"`. Nothing seems to work. What gives?!

Comment: I think this is a bug. If I assign `$element.elementType` to a variable and then use `$variable.endsWith("startevent")`, it works as expected. :-/

Comment: What version of Velocity are you using?

Comment: It's a plugin for another software product. I see `velocity-1.7.jar` and `velocity-tools-generic-1.4.jar` under the plugin folder.